# How to make Connect Communications VPN connection in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, vpn

these steps were send by my iSP admin for ver10.10 and i'm using 11.10...

step 1 sucessfully implemented till point 7 after that the problems are marked after '//'

Step 2 i cannot completely do the step 2

How to make Connect Communications VPN connection in Ubuntu 10.10.

```
1st Step:-
1- Go to System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manage
2- Search for “PPTP”, check “network-manager-PPTP” and click “Apply”
3- Click on the Network Manager tray icon with your right mouse button and choose “Edit Connections…”.
4- Go to the “VPN” tab and click “Add”.
5- Choose “Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)” as the VPN Connection Type
6- Check the VPN Connection Type and click “Create”.
7- Give your VPN connection a name and assign all the necessary information
•   Gateway = blue.connect.net.pk if you got Blue Package
or
•   Gateway = green.connect.net.pk if you got Green Package
or
•   Gateway = blueplus.connect.net.pk if you got BluePlus Package
or
•   Gateway = red.connect.net.pk if you got Red Package
•   User name = Connect Communications Userid
•   Password = Connect Communications Password
8- Now Click on “Advanced”
Authentication
•   Unchecked “PAP" // cannot uncheck
•   Unchecked “MSCHAP" // cannot uncheck
•   Unchecked “CHAP"
•   Checked only “MSCHAPv2"
EAP shown in ver11.10 and cannot be unchecked

Security And Compression.
•   Unchecked “Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)”.
•   Unchecked “Allow statefull encryption”.
•   Unchecked “Allow BSD data Compression”.
•   Unchecked “Allow Deflate data Compression”.
•   Unchecked “Use TCP Header Compression”.
•   Unchecked “Send PPP echo Packets”
Then Press “OK” then “Apply”.
9-Now you are able to connect to the specified VPN connection via the Networking Manager
Then you can connect to VPN in the menu bar and your Internet icon will have a lock when the connection is successful.
2nd Step:-
Open Terminal window.
First, you open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal):
Run command “sudo”
Now gave root Password.
Then run command “netstat -r -n”
It will show some lines and for example from the last line pick the IP from 2nd column like 10.111.0.1
0.0.0.0 10.111.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
Now run the fallowing command.
echo “route add -net 10.101.8.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.152.24.1” > /etc/rc.local
note :- 10.111.0.1 is an example IP
now run “ sh /etc/rc.local “
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls give more info on the actual problem you have, I mean, what happens when you try to connect?

Also, does the ISP want you to use any software or is it just all running through network manager?  Which, by the way, network manager is kinda buggy...

Also, what kind is your normal connection? ADSL?  PPPOE?

What do you mean you can't do all of step 2?

PPTP is not available is what you mean?  I have never heard of it...

I am not an expert, but some will come around.  Pls provide more info for them to use.